# mysql prevent displaying a row ONE which has reference in another row TWO but no reference in row THREE

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table like the following

```
id | name     | pid

1  | sam      | NULL

2  | sams ref | 1

3  | pam      | NULL
```

For the first time the first row gets inserted which will have pid as null
I insert a row which is related to the first row
and then i insert a row which is new and which may be referred by another row in future.

now i want only the third row to be displayed and not the first and second row as the second row contains the reference of first row.

so if any row has a reference to another row then both the rows should not be displayed.

Only rows which is not having any reference should be displayed.

BESIDES, IS IT A GOOD PRACTICE? PLEASE ADVICE ON THIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
SELECT 
A.*
FROM myTable A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable B ON B.PID = A.ID
WHERE A.PID IS NULL AND B.ID IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT 
A.*
FROM MyTable A
WHERE A.ID NOT IN
(
SELECT X.ID FROM MyTable X WHERE X.PID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Y.PID FROM MyTable Y WHERE Y.PID IS NOT NULL
)
```

As to whether this is good pratcice:

without knowing the requirements etc. I don't see how to discuss this...

Comment: Voila. working. i used the first statement and i will note the second one also. BESIDES... what is the inverse of my question? that is instead of the isolated one i want the rows which have reference.

Comment: @JayapalChandran usually this would need to be asked in a second question... basically you change "NOT IN" to "IN" in the second, while in the first you change "IS NULL" to "IS NOT NULL".

Comment: and... the query is returning zero results in the server. first i was using it in my local machine. will versions affect the way of execution of queries? version in server: 5.1.56 - version in my localhost: 5.1.30-community

Comment: @JayapalChandran it could be different between versions but most likely the data is just different...

Comment: now it is working... i forgot to set pid as null by default in the server.